# Regular Expression in .net

Tags: .net, regex

2 alpha

4 numeric

20 alpha/numeric

CCYYMMDD

how can i write regular expression for these inputs?

Comment: You need to be clearer - it's not at all obvious what the "CCYYMMDD" bit is meant to mean. If you could give some sample input and what you expect the output to be, that would be useful.

Comment: @Jon - you are so wise.  I thought it was clear, but I was mistaken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is useful](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet)

Answer (score 2):

2 Alpha -  `[A-Za-z]{2}`

4 Numeric - `\d{4}`

20 Alphanumeric - `[A-Za-z0-9]{20}` or if you really mean word characters (including `_`) `\w{20}`

CCYYMMDD - don't use a regex, use `DateTime.ParseExact( "yyyyMMdd" )`

The problem with trying to use a regular expression to parse dates is the backtracking that you have to do to handle the days in a month, particularly with February since it changes depending on whether its a leap year. I'm not even sure that it's possible using a regular expression alone and were it to be so I wouldn't want to look at the regular expression.

Comment: It IS possible, and true that you wouldn't want to look at it. (Its great as a puzzle, though...)

Comment: i already tried this 4 Numeric - \d{4} . But issue is it required me to must enter four digit i want digit can be max four and minimum 0

Comment: @SOF That's not what you asked for, but you can use `\d{0,4}` to get from 0 to 4 digits.

Comment: when i write  new Regex(@"\d{0,4}").Match("15654").Success; why it gives me true. While it is five digits

Comment: @SOF User - because it matches the first 4 digits.  To restrict it so that the string can only contain up to 4 digits and no more, you have to make it so that it matches the beginning and end around the 4 digits like so: `^\d{0,4}$`  -- that says, match the start of a line, up to 4 digits, then the end of the line.